# Linear equation for x

Tags: calculus

Let  we want to find the linear equation of  some lines, for both variable $x,y$.

So   $$m=\frac{(y_2-y_1)}{(x_2-x_1)},$$
and the equation is
$$y=m(x-x_1)+y_1,$$
and 
$$x=\frac{(y-y_1)}{m}+x_1,$$

if $m=\infty \text{ then }  y=\frac{-1}{m}(x-x_1)+y_1,$

when $m=\infty \text{ or }0$ how can I find the liear equation for $x$?

Should I find this from equation of $y$?

Comment: If your tangent is infinite, then your line is of the form $x=a$, whereas if your tangent is zero, the line is of the form $y=b$.

Comment: For $\infty$, try limits. As $m$ tends to $\infty$, RHS tends to $x_1$ or a point on the line. For $0$, $m$ becomes $0$ and we get the equation $y=y_1$.

Comment: @ JVV when tangent is zero, what is the equation for $x$?

Comment: When the tangent is zero, you have a horizontal line, and hence, $x$ varies over the reals. If you really wanted, you could write it as $x=t$, where $t \in \mathbb{R}$.